# Excel Function call

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do something like below. Why is the clearing not working?

```
Function bd() As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Call lol
End Function


Sub lol()
Sheets("Risk Analytics").Range("A1", "F99999").Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add little more text so that we can understand , what you actually want to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For `Range.Clear`, the start and end cell addresses are separated by a `:`. Like so

```
Sub lol()
    Sheets("Risk Analytics").Range("A1:F99999").Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: It still does not work. BTW , can i add sth like activecell.offset(1,0).value="asdasdas" into the lol sub.

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work"? Are you getting any error or is the `Range` just not clearing? Is the sheet name correct?

Comment: FWIW, it works for me in Excel 2013.  Double-check the sheet name - I bet there's a subtle difference between the actual sheet name and the string you're using (extra/missing space perhaps?)

Comment: @Jack., do you call your `Function bd()` from worksheet as `=bd()`? If so, it won't work because you can't modify cells usign UDF